# List Order by number value

Tags: apex, json, list, lightning-data-service, sort

i convert json to list:

```
[
        {
            name: "file.png",
            time: 1600813341124345
        },
        {
            name: "file2.png",
            time: 1600813385143605
        },
        {
            name: "file3.png",
            time: 1600979963651961
        }
]

public class JsonExample {
 public class Item{
    public string name {get; set;}
    public number time {get; set;}
 }

 public List<Item> items {get; set;}

 public static JsonExample parse(String json) {
    return (JsonExample) System.JSON.deserialize(json, JsonExample.class);
 }
}
```

and My controller

```
public JsonExample parse(String json) {
        return (JsonExample) System.JSON.deserialize(json, JsonExample.class);
    }
List< JsonExample.Item> objItems = parse(json_string);
```

All work fine but, i need to sort a values on list by key "time" desc

Comment: Take a look into the `comparable` interface.

Comment: i update the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add [Comparable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_comparable.htm) to your class:

```
public class Item implements Comparable {
  public Integer compareTo(Object other) {
    // return (Integer)(this.time - ((Item)other).time); // asc order
    return (Integer)(((Item)other).time - this.time); // desc order
  }
}
```

This will give you the values sorted in descending order when you call sort:

```
List< JsonExample.Item> objItems = parse(json_string);
objItems.sort();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for u answer this work, but order asc, how to order a desc?

Comment: @pedroooo See the edited example. Apparently I had it backwards from what you wanted.